# Task <T> retaining starting parameters

Tags: c#, multithreading

When creating a Task, is it possible to record the parameters that were used to start the task.

Take to following as an example (just a prototype, it's not real!).

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ICollection<Task<int>> taskList = new List<Task<int>>();

        // Create a set of tasks
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            var local_i = i; // Local scoped variable
            Task<int> t = new Task<int>(() =>
            {
                return myFunc(local_i);
            });
            t.Start();
            taskList.Add(t);
        }

        // Wait for all the tasks to complete.
        Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());


        // Output the results
        foreach (var tsk in taskList)
        {
            // the "???" should be the input value to the task
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Input: ??? - Result: "+tsk.Result);
        }

    }

    static int myFunc(int i)
    {
        return (i * i);
    }
```

When the results are output, I want to know what input variable was provided to `myFunc()` that produced the result

Comment: No it's not possible. But you can return an object that contains them. In you example a KeyValuePair<Int32, Int32> or a custom object.

Comment: Not related to your questions but any reason why you want to create cold tasks rather than hot ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides returning a `Tuple` with both values, you can also make `taskList` an `ICollection<Tuple<int, Task<int>>>` and store the parameter there. To make it simpler, you might create your own class for that:

```
class TaskInfo<T>
{
     public Task<T> Task { get; set; }
     public T Parameter { get; set; }
}
```

And then

```
var taskList = new List<TaskInfo<int>>();
...
taskList.Add(new TaskInfo { Task = t, Parameter = local_i });
```

Comment: I'd use this approach, because it doesn't involve changing the method called by the task, and it keeps the extra data at the logical level at which it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change `myFunc` change the return type, so it will return the input and result as a `Tuple`.

If you can't you could use a `Dictionary` or `List<Tuple<input,Task>>` to store the input along with the task (instead of your `ICollection`)